# more than 1 form at one page

Tags: php, html

I've problem with multiple form at one page. At page index I include 4 forms

```
include('./poll_1a.php');
include('./poll_2a.php');
include('./poll_3a.php');
include('./poll_4a.php');
```

The form code at every poll page is the same. I include some unique markers ($poll_code) for every scripts but the effect is when I use one form - the sending variable are received in the others. But I would like to work each form individually.

The variable $poll_code is unique for every script -> 1 for poll_1, 2 for poll_2 etc.
The same situation is with $cookie_name

```
$cookie_name = "poll_cookie_".$poll_code;
```

than, as I see, cookies have different names.

```
 $poll_code = "1"; // or 2, 3, 4
 ?>
 <p>    
  <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="post" name="<?php echo $poll_code; ?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="poll_cookie_<?php echo $poll_code; ?>" value="<?php echo $poll_code; ?>">
  <table>
<?php
  //print possible answers
  for($i=0;$i<count($answers);$i++){
    ?><tr><td style="\text-allign: left;\"><input type="radio" name="vote_<?php echo $poll_code; ?>" value="<?php echo $i; ?>"> <?php echo $answers[$i]; ?></td></tr><?php
  }
  echo "</table>";
  echo "<br>";

if ($_COOKIE["$cookie_name"] == $poll_code ) { 
  echo "<br> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; nie można głosować ponownie ...";
} else {  
?>

    <p><input type="submit" name="submit_<?php echo $poll_code; ?>" value="głosuj !" onClick="this.disabled = 'true';"></p>

<?php    
    }
?>  

  </form>
</p>
```

Q: how to make this forms to work individually at one page?

//------------------- EDIT

the receiving part of the script

```
  $votes = file($file);
  $total = 0;
  $totale = 0;
  $poll_cookie = 0;

if (isset($_POST["vote_$poll_code"]) &&  isset($_POST["poll_cookie_$poll_code"])) {
  $vote = $_POST["vote_$poll_code"]; 
  $poll_cookie = $_POST["poll_cookie_$poll_code"];
  }

  //submit vote
  if(isset($vote)){
    $votes[$vote] = $votes[$vote]+1;
  }

  //write votes
  $handle = fopen($file,"w");

  foreach($votes as $v){
    $total += $v;
    fputs($handle,chop($v)."\n");
  }

  fclose($handle);
```

Of course, the $file have the unique declaration too (at top of the script, under the $poll_code declaration).

```
$file = "poll_".$poll_code.".txt";
```

Comment: What does it mean for "forms to work individually at one page"?

Comment: This forms are polls - I want the user will vote for each poll separately and not once in all :)

Comment: I still have absolutely no idea what you're trying to ask.

Comment: Shouldn't you be setting `$poll_code` to the unique value before each include happens? Also `<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>"` is an XSS vulnerability.

Comment: Are you saying you have 4 forms but you're getting the same data submitted for each form no matter what you select in each? We need to see the contents of your form scripts too (poll_1a.php, etc)

Comment: I think he is trying to say that he has 4 polls on one page, and that at this time when he casts a vote (or whatever) on 1 poll, it casts the vote to all 4 polls, and that is not what he wants.

Comment: @MrCode -> $poll_code = "1"; ect. is declared at the top of the script

Comment: @Bono _> thank you, that is my problem. I vote in first poll but the same vote I receive in 1,2,3 and 4 poll.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue might be that `<?php echo $poll_code; ?>` is outside the loop so maybe that it's always using the same value assigned to it, maybe put it inside the loop

Comment: thnks, can you show me a point in script you are think about? This variable is (as I think) individual for every copy of script. This is working couse the cookies have unique names and unique variables inside.

Comment: Could you add the returning html which the PHP generates ?